# .load() loads webpage containing a datepicker and rangeslider but they don't work (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-slider

On my main webpage main.htm, I have a div button which when clicked it loads another webpage called searchhotel.htm. Inside searchhotel.htm I have a JQuery datepicker and a rangeslider. When I upload these pages onto a server, if I go directly to searchhotel.htm the datepicker and rangesliders work. But when I'm on main.htm and I click on "search" which loads searchhotel.htm into the main div, the only thing that shows is the date textbox and the datepicker doesn't show up and neither does the rangeslider.

main.htm

```
<html>
<head>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function my_loader(array) {

            switch(array) {

                case "search": $('#mainpanel').load("searchhotel.htm");
                break;

            }
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "top_title_panel">
    <div id = "title_div"><span id = "title">Hello</span></div>
</div>
<div id = "btn_panel_div">
    <div id = "search"  class = "btn_div" onClick= "my_loader(this.id)">Search Hotel</div>
        </div>
<div id = "mainpanel"></div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

searchhotel.htm

```
<html>
<head>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.custom.js"></script>
    <script src="jQRangeSlider-min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/iThing.css" type="text/css" />

    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<p>HI</p>
<div>       
    <script>
            $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker(
                {dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
            });
            $(function() {
                $( "#slider" ).rangeSlider();
            });

    </script>
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
    <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

does anyone have any ideas why I the datepicker and sliders don't show up from main.htm?

Comment: You realize, when you .load that html page you're loading in a new copy of jquery too, right? (that's bad if you weren't aware)

Comment: It doesn't work because the javascript is executing before the elements exist. Read the documentation for .load in the api: http://api.jquery.com/load specifically the section about script execution.

Comment: No I didn't. I'm new to JQuery. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Yeah, it works now. Thank you. I just took out the new copy of JQuery and put it all in main.htm and it works now.